# Cambiar la orientación al escribir en PDF Android Studio

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

Hola amigos tengo esta duda mi app genera y escribe una tabla en un pdf sin embargo como puedo hacer para que la orientación del pdf sea  de vertical a horizontal(y viceversa) les comparto la clase donde realizo la creación y escritura del pdf

```
public void openDcomunet() {
        createFile();
        try {
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
            document.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("oppenDocuent", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void createFile() {
        File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "PDF");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdirs();
        }
        pdfFile = new File(folder, "Archivo.pdf");
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando crees tu documento de vertical a horizontal y viceversa al crear tu documento usa:

```
PageSize.A4.Rotate()
```

Ejemplo:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfecto

Comment: Excelente Luis!, saludos!